# can we convert ui controller into xml in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I want to convert UI controller to XML file. I'm going to save that UI controller file (XML File) in server. Then I can do customize the  UI controllers and dynamically add in Objective C.
is it possible ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but you may run afoul of the app store submission guidelines. I don't know if your app will be allowed into the store or not, you'd have to ask Apple.

Personally I would use nib files:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContetnsOfURL:...];
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithData:data bundle:nil];

NSArray *nibObjects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
```

Basically a nib file can contain anything, you create them with interface builder as "xib" files, and then compile those xib files into nib files, which are smaller and faster.

The "nibObjects" array will contain whatever views and controller objects you choose to put in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Yes ! app will be rejected because of it. I want to know additional thing. I am going to save customize controller details in the server. EX : If it lable, <label name>,<Type>, I'll be save in the server. label name means display name.("Discipline"), Type means UIlabel, UITextField or UISegemnted Controller. After getting this information in server and can I build own controller in pragmatically ?? App will be rejected because of this ?

Comment: I don't know what they will reject, you have to ask them.